Trying to identify a vintage (1992) diode
I'd like to identify the vintage diode at position D15:

This diode is found on a PCB from a 1992 Mercedes 300D (W124) Convenience Control Unit (it controls the windows, sunroof, etc.). I don't think there are any other markings on it.
It is testing bad (short) and so I think I need to replace it. So, bonus points if you can tell me a Manufacturer/Part no. that would be a suitable substitute (pretty sure ITT doesn't make these anymore).
Any help would be most appreciated.
Later... I unsoldered one side and found that, yes, there were additional markings: "ZY 22"; I tested it again and it tested GOOD.

I used a Fluke DMM in diode test mode. For the pictured diode (D15), I got forward voltage drop of 0.609V, reverse current voltage: 1.163V. There's another identically marked diode on the board at position D37. Conducting the same test for it, I got forward voltage drop of 0.605V and reverse current voltage of "0L" meaning no current, no voltage. Before doing these tests, I discharged all the caps although the board hasn't been plugged in for awhile.

I just found a similar style diode in the following link https://www.ebay.com/itm/385126779160 Maybe there is a marking on the other side, can you unsolder it to check if there is additionnal marking?

OK, I unsoldered one side and found that, yes, there were additional markings: "ZY 22". So I assume that's a Zener diode 22V? Does the 'Y' indicate tolerance? Thanks @vivier!

@jsotola: No, I had measured in circuit. When I unsoldered it, I tested it again and it tested GOOD: reverse current voltage: "0L". So, now I know to test suspect diodes out of circuit before thinking them defective. Thanks for asking the right questions!

The answer then for a marking "ZY 22" of ITT brand is:
ZY22 zener diode from ITT
example of a neighbour designation (ZY68) seen on ebay :


(ZY seems to be the name of zener diode series)

The ZY22 is a 2W, 22V silicon, so called "zener" diode (actually it is a diode with controlled avalanche characteristic).
